# using packages dplyr and data.table in same session causes copy error in mutate()

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I want to use the fast fread function of the data.table package to load a huge csv file. After loading I want to convert a string variable to a factor. But when I want to do a mutate on the loaded file like this:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

df <- fread("df.csv")
df <- mutate(df, name = as.factor(name))
```

I get this error:

```
Error in mutate.data.table(df, df = df, df = ,  : 
  could not find function "copy
```

I tried to detach the data.table package before doing the mutate, but that doesn't help. I still get that error.

Does anyone knows how to handle this problem? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't reproduce this on my machine: `library(data.table);
library(dplyr);dt <- data.table(iris);
dt <- mutate(dt, name = as.factor(Species))
`

Comment: fyi, the `data.table` way is `df[, name := as.factor(name)]` (which btw doesn't copy and modifies in place)

Comment: Why mixing up dplyr and data.table? `data.table` is a great piece of software - just stick to it, it's best.... All hail to data.table!

Comment: obscure sql language + obscure r language = great piece of software!

Comment: I use dplyr in all my scripts. data.table is new to me. I just wanted it to use for the csv file loading. That's why i mixed it up.

Comment: data.table replaces the need for *plyr and reshape, take the time to learn its syntax, its the best thing since sliced bread

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `copy` is from the `data.table` package. So when you *detach* `data.table`, `dplyr` can't find the function `copy` (for some reason it was not properly imported).

As Hadley said in the comments, this is actually a bug in dplyr, and should not happen anymore in dplyr 0.3.

Reproducing your error:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

# Creating the data.table
df <- data.table(name = 1:10)

#detaching data.table, this will cause the error
detach(package:data.table)

#dplyr can't find copy
mutate(df, name=as.factor(name))

Error in mutate.data.table(df, name = as.factor(name)) : 
  could not find function "copy"
```

Note that the error does not occur when both packages are loaded:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.table(name = 1:10)
mutate(df, name=as.factor(name))
    name
 1:    1
 2:    2
 3:    3
 4:    4
 5:    5
 6:    6
 7:    7
 8:    8
 9:    9
10:   10
```

Comment: That's actually technically a bug in dplyr - it's fixed in 0.3